# getMessage() without overriding in Exception

Tags: java, exception, overriding

I have a class which extends Exception, but I am not allowed to override `getMessage()` from Exception so I got to find a way around it.

Just for a visualisation of the task, here is a example:

```
public class NoCertificateException extends Exception {

    private Student[] students;

public NoCertificateException(Student[] students) {
        this.students = students;

public String getMessage() {
        String arrayToString = Arrays.toString(students);
        String s =  " has/have no certificate(s)";
        return arrayToString + s;
}
```

but in this case `getMessage()` gets overriden

Comment: Invoke `super(theMessageYouWant)` in the constructor.

Comment: "*I am not allowed to override `getMessage()`*" - Why not? --- [Class `Exception` has a constructor `Exception(String message)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Exception.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)).

Comment: As I am still a student in the first semester it is a task we have to do for practice and we get no solutions, so I struggled on this one:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exception` [has a constructor which takes a string](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Exception.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)), which is then used as the message.

So, invoke that constructor inside your constructor:

```
public NoCertificateException(Student[] students) {
  super(Arrays.toString(students) + " has/have no certificate(s)");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! just solved it perfectly:)

Comment: @SerkanBesim In that case, consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).